# Rabbitmq: Listening in MQTT

Tags: stream, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

Here I will explain my desired used case:

- I create a durable queue for a mqtt client (**mqtt-subscription-client1qos1**) before the device connect to the broker. Exchange (**amp.topic**)
- I create some bindings for that queue (**topic1**, **topic2**)
- I send 1 message to **topic1** (using amqp)
- I send 1 message to **topic2** (using amqp)
- Then using MQTT client setting client="**client1**" I connect to "**topic1**" using the same exchange (**amp.topic**)

How many messages I suppose to get? I expect 1, but I am getting 2 , and I am not sure I am testing right or if this is the expected beheavior.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AMQP, which RabbitMQ is engineered around, messages are always published to an **exchange**, routed according to **routing keys and bindings** and consumed from a **queue**.

In MQTT, messages are published to the **broker**, routed according to **topics** and consumed via a **subscription**.

The [RabbitMQ MQTT plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) maps these concepts together:

- The MQTT **broker** is emulated by a single **exchange**
- The MQTT **topic** is used as a **routing key**
- The MQTT **subscription** is a **binding** from that exchange to a queue
- Finally, each MQTT **client** has a **queue** from which it can receive its subscribed messages

The key thing here is that these are just ordinary RabbitMQ exchanges and queues, used to emulate the MQTT model - messages can be routed by the broker to any queue, and messages from other brokers can be routed to the queue, and they don't need to relate to the topics you've defined in MQTT.

So if you manually route a message into the queue for a particular MQTT client, RabbitMQ will deliver it to the client along with other messages in that queue. The "topic" that the client is subscribed won't make any difference, because that is used only to set up the *binding* on the server.